# I am passing an object to a template in Django but I can not call it

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

I am in Django, I am making a list of objects in my **views.py** so I can pass it to my template and show those properties in my page.

I create the list of objects and their properties like this:
**views.py:**

```
def courseListView(request):
    object_list = {}
    courses = Course.objects.all()
    for course in courses:
        object_list[course] = {
            'prog': int(lessonsCompleted.objects.filter(user=request.user.id, course=course.id).count() / course.lessons.count() * 100),
            'title': course.title,
            'slug': course.slug,
            'thumbnail': course.thumbnail,
            'get_absolute_url': '/' + course.slug,     
        }

    context = {
        'object_list': object_list,
    }
    
    return render(request, "courses/course_list.html", context)
```

In this way I am populating a object called `object_list` with a number of objects I extract from my *Course* model.

In the template I try calling the properties of the objects in `object_list` like this:
**template:**

```
{% block content %}

{% load static %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/courses.css' %}">

    <div class="container d-flex justify-content-center">
        <div class="row">
            <h1>Cursos</h1>
            <div class="container-fluid mt-4 d-flex card-deck justify-content-center">
            {% for object in object_list %}
            <div class="row justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-auto mb-3">
                    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                        <img class="card-img-top" src="/static/{{ object.thumbnail }}" alt="Card image cap">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h5 class="card-title"><a href="{{ object.get_absolute_url }}">{{ object.title }}</a></h5>
                            <div class="w3-light-grey w3-round-xlarge">
                                <div class="w3-container w3-blue w3-round-xlarge" id="progress-{{ object.slug }}" style="width:{{ object.prog }}%;">{{ object.prog }}%</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-footer">
                                <a href="{{ object.get_absolute_url }}" class="btn btn-primary">Ver curso</a>
                            </div>
                            <script>console.log({{ object_list }});</script>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>    
            {% endfor %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

As a result, when I render my template I can see the properties of my objects that are in the model, but I can not see the property *'prog'* that I create and add to the objects in my `object_list` in my **views.py** file.

Here is my *Course* model in case it helps:
**models.py:**

```
class Course(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField()
    allowed_memberships = models.ManyToManyField(Membership)
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("courses:detail", kwargs={"slug": self.slug})
        
    @property    
    def lessons(self):
        return self.lesson_set.all().order_by('position')
```

Why can I not access the *'prog'* property? I have populated a list of objects with properties manually, why can I not access one of them in my template?

Comment: `object_list` is a *dictionary*, so if you iterate over it, you iterate over the *keys*, not the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but I can not see the property `prog` that I create and add to the objects in my `object_list`. This is not a property. You created a *dictionary* that maps `Course` objects to dictionaries. The `prog` item is in the dictionary in the associated value.

You can iterate with:

```
{% for object, props in object_list.items %}
    …
    {{ object.title }}
    {{ props.prog }}
{% endfor %}
```

It however does not make much sense to pass the `title`, `slug`, etc. in the dictionary, since these are just attributes of the object. In your template, you did not use these items of the dictionary, you simply used the attributes of the `Course` object.

It is likely also not a good idea to make queries to calculate the progress. This will result in an *N+1 problem* where in order to render *N* courses, you make one query to obtain all the courses, and (in this case) *2×N* queries to calculate the progress for each course. You can take a look at [`.annotate(…)` [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) for this.

Comment: Thank you so much, I have been stuck on this one for weeks. I didn't know I could do that kind of iteration. This worked straight away in my case. The next step is to delve into and understand .annotate() to make my algorithm more efficient. A million thanks